# Script to copy and paste new google form responses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My classes uses a Google Form that students use to sign up for help.  We need to edit responses when someone comes and doesn't come, so we were looking to set up a script that can copy and paste the new form responses from Form Responses 1 sheet to sheet2 that doesn't overwrite the data already in sheet2.  Is there a way to do this with a script?  Looking to automate it since we have some teachers who aren't good with using Google Sheets.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome. What language were you thinking of using for this app? Is it Google Apps Script itself, or is it another language like Python or Ruby, maybe? The documentation for using Google Apps Scripts with forms is really comprehensive. Check it out here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Comment: Was looking to just use the built in Google apps script.  I'll check out the documentation in the meantime to see if I can figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Take a crack at it and if there's something that just won't work no matter how hard you try, stick the code up here and there'll be someone who can figure it out. Go get 'em.

Comment: Hi Thomas, it is possible to achieve what you are looking for with Apps Script. Could you provide a sample of the form students use to "sign up for help" ?

Comment: I understand that “sign up for help form” is pasting student responses in “Form Responses 1” sheet. You want the available form's questions' response choices to change if the student was in class or not. You can avoid overwriting data by pasting the data outside of the response sheet’s data range, which you can fetch with [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange). Provide more detail of your response sheets pls.

Comment: Here is a copy of the spreadsheet we are using.  I had to make a copy since the original has student info on it, but you can see the gist of what we are doing.  The data comes in on sheet 1 and then we copy it over to sheet 2 so we can make if they came or not.  We also have it sorted so newest dates are on top.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-IYcAOaeyvWKcaCJg111uEZ-d4FwQDLU_BhkQTGV-Gw/edit?usp=sharing